# running python script of global keyboard shortcut in OSx

Tags: automator, python, services

Hi I wrote a python script to get the size of the file of which I have URL I copied from browser or anywhere; I wanted to create a global keyboard shortcut so I tried to create using Automator > Service > Run a shell Script and selected `\usr\bin\python`

and pasted the below script to execute:

```
from pySan import utils
import Tkinter as tk
import urllib
import os
import sys

def main():

        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()


        # get text from clipboard
        data =  root.clipboard_get()

        if not data:
                print "nothing in clipboard to get file size."
                return

        site = urllib.urlopen(data)
        meta = site.info()

        if meta.keys():
                contentLength = meta.get("Content-Length", None)
                if not contentLength:
                        print "Failed to retrieve or no data available for size"
                        return
                length = int(contentLength)
                print "Size of %s: %s " % (os.path.basename(data), ''.join(utils.sizeof(length)) )
                sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

but it seems to give error, workflow failed. what am I doing wrong .

Comment: Did your really select \usr\bin\python or was it /usr/bin/python

Comment: I probably misstyped in SE, as I didnt copied pasted exactly from Automator's window.